# Laravel 8 "We can't find a user with that email address." error when trying to reset passwords

Tags: php, laravel

I encountered this problem yesterday and I tried to solve this but no luck. I was confused, this function is from Laravel default and I didn't change the code but it gave me this error even though the email existed in the Database. All functions were fine except this reset function.
[image]
I have a user table also in the database.
[image]

I've done everything by checking the core Laravel code (passwords.php, senpasswordresetsemail.php, etc) but no result, here is my user migration and my user model code.

**user migration code**

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->string('user_role')->nullable();
        $table->integer('company_number')->nullable();
        $table->string('project_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('group_name')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**User model code**

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements LdapAuthenticatable {
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, PowerJoins, AuthenticatesWithLdap;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'user_role',
        'company_number',
        'project_id',
        'group_name',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function companies() {
        return $this->hasOne(Company::class, 'company_number', 'company_number');
    }
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks! :D